# Kivy Launcher: Can't find path /storage/emulated/0/kivy

Tags: kivy

I'm trying to use the kivy launcher on Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 and I can't find where to place my project. Can't find the folder.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching a lot I finally find my answer. I was looking for a book in ebook reader app and the app was showing me the folder path and I finally find the storage/emulated/0. It's the default folder for the internal storage not the Card. So I placed my project there and worked :) Now I'm happy.